# How to import boolean by using "Yes" or "No"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I import the data when it is "No", the boolean is false?  For e.g. I declare the arrived is boolean.  But I can't import the data on below code.

```
Asset.create!(:arrived => "No")
```

It return arrived: true

Thanks

Patrick Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Ruby except `nil` and `false` are considered `true` values.
You will have to perform some check on it.

```
some_string == 'No'
Asser.create!(arrived: some_string == 'No' ? false : true) # will equal false

some_string == 'Yes'
Asser.create!(arrived: some_string == 'No' ? false : true) # will equal true
```